# one regular expression to check length of non-numeric and non-punctuation characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check a string which length of non-numeric and non-punctuation characters is between 3 and 10. But I think it's hard to manage it in just one regular expression, so how can I do that?

For example:

`,,,,,,1231` is not ok, because length of non-numeric and non-punctuation characters is 0.

`1abcdefghij111` is ok, because non-numeric and non-punctuation characters part is `abcdefghij`, the length of that is 10.

Comment: Is that between 3 and 10 inclusive? E.g. can the character occur 3 times to 10 times; or 4 times to 9 times; or some combination of the two? Also, are the non-numeric & non-punctuation characters always sequential/touching each other?

Comment: @tonitone120 the character can occur 3 times to 10 times, and the non-numeric & non-punctuation characters can be everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Match the start of the string, then zero or more numeric or punctuation characters in a character set.

Match one non-numeric, non-punctuation character, then match zero or more numeric or punctuation characters. Repeat the above 3 to 10 times, then match zero or more numeric or punctuation characters until you get to the end of the string.

```js
const test = (str) => {
  console.log(/^[\d.,]*(?:[^\d.,][\d.,]*){3,10}[\d.,]*$/.test(str));
};
test(',,,,,,1231'); // false
test(',,,,,,aa'); // false
test(',,,,,,aaa'); // true
```

- `^[\d.,]*` - Start of string and possible leading characters
- `(?:[^\d.,][\d.,]*){3,10}` - Match a non-digit, non-punc character 3 times, possibly interspersed with digit or punc characters
- `[\d.,]*$` - End of string and possible trailing characters
  `